# how to add nodes to Distance Matrix service request

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using [Distance Matrix service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) but there is no mentioning how I can request for several points and get an optimal route for them. Is it a known issue? has anybody solved it?

Comment: I need at least to be able to request several route points

Answer (score 0):

Your using the wrong API.

To get an 'optimal' route, aka solving Travelling Salesman Problem, use the Directions API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

and the `optimize:true` paramater.

Comment: thanks for the answer. As I understand 'sub_steps' are nodes between start and end point and route should be optimized, taking into account these 'sub_steps'?

Comment: No. From the docs *sub_steps contains detailed directions for walking or driving steps in transit directions. Substeps are only available when travel_mode is set to "transit". *